# Getting value of QUERY row stored in postgres array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, function, postgresql-9.4

```
DECLARE 
  resources varchar[];
  default_active development.switch_state;
  defaultsp varchar[];
  x varchar[];
  columnname varchar;
  looper integer;

BEGIN
  -- setting resources
  resources := array(SELECT column_name::text AS resource FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='usr_defprivilegies');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_defprvg');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_category');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_level');
  -- setting privilegies switch
  SELECT ap.default_active AS switcher INTO default_active FROM development.usr_activeprivilegies AS ap 
INNER JOIN development.usr_managelayer AS um ON ap.id_activeprvg = um.id_activeprvg WHERE um.id_user = $1;

  IF default_active = '1' THEN
    looper := 1;
    FOREACH x SLICE 1 IN ARRAY resources
    LOOP
      columnname := resources[looper];
      defaultsp := array(SELECT columnname FROM development.usr_defprivilegies AS dp WHERE dp.id_category = $4 AND dp.id_level = $3);
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE development.usr_activeprivilegies SET default_active = ''0'', '
    || resources[looper]
    || ' = '
    || quote_literal(defaultsp[looper])
    || ' WHERE id_activeprvg = '
    || $2;
      looper := looper + 1;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

RETURN 1;
END;
```

I need access to values of columns stored in array, but i can't find a way to do it. That's code works fine, but this line:

```
quote_literal(defaultsp[looper])
```

Returns something like this: 'column_name' but i need 'column_value';

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION for changing privilegies after login, two tables default X active, default is a set of rules based on category and level of users, privilegies are adaptable, and we get the source of resources from information_schema in postgres, this is parametr for loop.

```
DECLARE 
  resources varchar[];
  resource varchar;
  res_count integer;
  default_active development.switch_state;
  defaultsp development.switch_state;
  looper integer;

BEGIN
  -- setting resources
  resources := array(SELECT column_name::text AS resource FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='usr_defprivilegies');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_defprvg');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_category');
  resources := array_remove(resources, 'id_level');
  -- setting privilegies switch
  SELECT ap.default_active AS switcher INTO default_active FROM development.usr_activeprivilegies AS ap 
    INNER JOIN development.usr_managelayer AS um ON ap.id_activeprvg = um.id_activeprvg WHERE um.id_user = $1;
  -- setting privilegies
  IF default_active = '1' THEN
    looper := 1;
    res_count := array_length(resources, 1);

    LOOP
      resource := 'dp.' || resources[looper];
      EXECUTE 'SELECT ' 
        || resource 
        || ' FROM development.usr_defprivilegies AS dp WHERE dp.id_category = ' 
        || quote_literal($4) 
        || ' AND dp.id_level = ' 
        || quote_literal($3) INTO defaultsp;

      EXECUTE 'UPDATE development.usr_activeprivilegies SET '
        || resources[looper]
        || ' = '
        || quote_literal(defaultsp)
        || ' WHERE id_activeprvg = '
        || $2;

      looper := looper + 1;
      EXIT WHEN looper > res_count;
    END LOOP;

    EXECUTE 'UPDATE development.usr_activeprivilegies SET updateby = ' 
      || quote_literal($1) 
      || ', updatedate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, default_active = ' 
      || quote_literal(0);
  END IF;

RETURN 1;
END;
```

This works fine;